# String string = "" + childDataSnapshot.child(key).getValue())

Tags: android, firebase, snapshot

So I've got a set of children, that I want to get the values of, but the key could be anything so I need to use a variable. However when I run this code I get Null for values?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
'*********

```
public void dataSnapshotSift(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            String key = childDataSnapshot.getKey();
            String value = "" + childDataSnapshot.child(key).getValue();

            Log.v("Firebase: ", key);
            Log.v("Firebase: ", "" + childDataSnapshot.child(key).getValue());

        }
    }
```

'*********** Here is the logCat

```
07-31 23:48:23.702 V/Firebase poss count:: 3
07-31 23:48:23.702 V/FireBase:: Value:     DataSnapshot { key = T2, value = {33=P00006, 4=P00003, 1=P00001} }
07-31 23:48:23.702  V/Firebase:: 1
07-31 23:48:23.702  V/Firebase:: null
07-31 23:48:23.702  V/Firebase:: 4
07-31 23:48:23.702  V/Firebase:: null
07-31 23:48:23.702  V/Firebase:: 33
07-31 23:48:23.702  V/Firebase:: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm giving my answer based upon the assumption that your database structure looks something like this:

```
{ 
    T2: {
        33: P00006,
        4: P00003,
        1: P00001
    },
   ...
}
```

Here's the code you have for `value`:

`String value = "" + childDataSnapshot.child(key).getValue();`

But `childDataSnapshot` doesn't have a child with a value of `key`. For example, the `childDataSnapshot` with a key of `33` doesn't also have a child of `33`. Instead you want to just get the value of the `childDataSnapshot`.

`String value = "" + childDataSnapshot.getValue();`

Comment: Jen, you're like the Sherlock Holmes of firebase and now that you've laid it out I feel like Dr. Watson. Its so simple, so obvious. Thank you.